# Cache Simulator in Java, Implementing Data Block

Tags: java, arrays, caching

In creating my cache simulator, I realized that I need a structure that holds the block of data that is normally copied from main memory to the cache. In this case, it's holding 8 numbers. I've setup my cache as an object so that I can set it's Tag, Valid Bit, Dirty Bit, and finally the data block. So I'm thinking an array would be the best thing to do here. Would my getters and setters just be :

```
public int[] getDataBlock() {
    return dataBlock;
}
public void setDataBlock(int[] dataBlock) {
    this.dataBlock = dataBlock;
}
```

If they are, how do I initialize the cache to all 0?

```
//initialize cache slots to 0
for (int i = 0; i<cache.length; i++) {
    cache[i] = new SlotNode();
    cache[i].setValidBit(0);
    cache[i].setTag(0);
    for (int j = 0; j < cache.length; j++) {
        cache[i].setDataBlock([0]);
    }
    //cache[i].setData(0);
    cache[i].setDirty(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a helper function to clear a cache slot like this:

```
public void clearData(){
   Arrays.fill(this.dataBlock,0);
}
```

To copy from main mem to a particular slot, use [System.arraycopy](http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=641):

```
public void copyToCacheSlot(int[] mainMem, int baseIndex, int length){
    if (length <= 8)
        System.arraycopy(mainMem, baseIndex, this.dataBlock, 0, length);
    else
        //Copied too much 
}
```

Loop through your `cache` array and call the above functions accordinly for **each element**.

Comment: The `cache[i].setDataBlock([0]);` should have been modified to show that I didn't know what to do to initialize the array's values to 0. And sorry for the n00bness But I set the constructor with the other values in the cacheNode class. My thought behind that is that each SLOT will need a separate array, or block of data.

Comment: `public class SlotNode {
       public int validBit;
       public int tag;
       public int []dataBlock = new int[8];
       public int dirty;
 
 public int[] getDataBlock() {
  return dataBlock;
 }

 public void setDataBlock(int[] dataBlock) {
  this.dataBlock = dataBlock;
 }

 public int getDirty() {
               return dirty;
       }
       public void setDirty(int dirty) {
               this.dirty = dirty;
       }



}

Comment: So you're saying, a cache has multiple slots and each slot is an array?

Comment: This particular cache has 8 slots and each slot contains a bunch of different variables: a Valid bit, Dirty Bit, Tag (identifier), and finally this 8 byte block of values that you basically copy from this other array (the "main memory"). So what I need to eventually do is copy values x through x+8 in the main_memory array to cache[slot_number].setDataBlock or something like that..

Comment: I've edited my answer. You can use Arrays.fill to fill each array with whatever value as demonstrated. You'll have to do some math figure out how to copy from main mem for each cache slot, I've only shown how to do it for 1 slot.

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try this out